# Can Random Forest regression handle non-stationary input variables?

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, time-series

I am working on a project where the explanatory variables include soil attributes, land use and land cover properties, stream flow and climate (precipitation, temperature etc) measurements recorded at multiple locations across a study area. I am proposing to use a random forest regression model to predict the response (an eco-indicator) at these locations.

1. Soil attributes and land-use/land-cover data are available as single measurements at each location.
2. Stream flow and climate data are available as a time series. From these time series data I was hoping to extract long-term representative values such as mean daily stream flow, average annual precipitation total, average annual temperature and so on.

However during exploratory data analysis I noticed that at several locations in the study area the annual time series of stream flow and climate variables are exhibiting non-stationarity. I am aware that it is possible stationarize these series using techniques such as detrending or differencing. However, I would like to know if random forests can handle non stationary inputs (without stationarizing)? Are there any best practices when dealing with such data sets?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions purely about statistical methods should be directed to [stats.se]. There doesn't seem to be a specific programming question here that would be appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: In short, I believe the answer is: if you're looking to do sort of forecasting, where the trend of a time-series would matter, don't use a random forest. If you're hoping to look, say one day ahead of your data, then a random forest will likely work very well.

Comment: Thank you directing me to the question on Cross Validated about random forest regression and trended time series. Really appreciate it.